# Jquery autocomplete not working MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, autocomplete

I have two models.  One of the models (my ViewModel) is tied to the textbox in the form and the other model is tied to an entity (Employees) that I'm using to autocomplete the textbox (VieModel.Name).  I followed a tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762959/jQuery-UI-Autocomplete-in-MVC-Selecting-Nested-Ent) and cannot seem to get it working.  I delved around Google, as well.  It may be my newness to Entity Framework or the fact I'm using a ViewModel not tied to an entity and a Model tied to an entity.

Ultimately I am trying to autocomplete the Name in the ViewModel from the FirstName + LastName from the Employees Entity Model, but am trying FirstName for now.

Model from entity:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public bool ActiveFlag { get; set; }
    public int EmpNid { get; set; }
    public string RecKey { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    ... etc
```

My ViewModel not tied to entity but posted with this form:

```
public class SalesViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The employee name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ... etc
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name,
        new
        {
            @class = "employees-autocomplete",
            data_url = Url.Action("EmployeesAutocomplete", "Employee")
        })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

My Jquery at the bottom of the page:

```
$(function () {
    $('.employees-autocomplete').autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var url = $(this.element).data('url');

            $.getJSON(url, { term: request.term }, function (data) {
                response(data);
            })
        }
    });
})
```

My JsonResult Controller:

```
public JsonResult EmployeesAutocomplete(string term)
{
    Employee[] matching = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(term) ?
         db.Employees.ToArray() :
         db.Employees.Where(p => p.FirstName.ToUpper().StartsWith(term.ToUpper())).ToArray();

    return Json(matching.Select(m => new
    {
        id = m.EmpNid,
        value = m.FirstName,
        label = m.ToString()
    }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Am I supposed to be doing anything in the post or get request? Not sure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine. The only issue i see is, you are calling the `ToString()` on the Employee entity object/record for the label value. Since this is the value to be shown to the user, you probably want to use your FirstName or any string properties here ( Unless you overwrote the a `ToString()` method in your Employee class to return a string version)

Replace this

```
return Json(matching.Select(m => new
{
    id = m.EmpNid,
    value = m.FirstName,
    label = m.ToString()
}), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

With this

```
return Json(matching.Select(m => new
{
    id = m.EmpNid,
    value = m.FirstName,
    label = m.FirstName +' '+m.LastName 
}), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

As per the comment

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function)

This usually happens when you are trying to use jQuery before it is defined in your page. Double check the following steps

1. Include jQuery before everything else
2. Include jQuery UI after jQuery library
3. Execute your page level scripts only after loading the dependeny libraries (jQuery/jQueryUI). You can do this by calling your page level scripts inside a script section.

   ```
   @section scripts
   {
     $(function(){

      // Your code for initializing the auto complete goes here

     })
   }
   ```

   Assuming your layout has a section called scripts which is defined after loading jQuery and jQuery UI libraries.

So in your layout file, it should be like this

```
@RenderBody()
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: I start typing in the text box and still nothing.  Is it odd that I don't even see anything in the developer console or network tabs as I start typing?

Comment: Do you have any error in your console ? Check your network tab and see whether it is making the call your server. what is the response coming back ?

Comment: It's not making a call or returning errors.  I just set a breakpoint in my JsonResult EmployeesAutocomplete class (I should have done this before asking) and it's not even getting in there when I start typing.

Comment: Actually, on page load I got: Sales:261 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ Sales:261 which points to the start of my jquery function for the autocomplete. Edit: Upon further guesses I put the jquery.js on the top of my _Layout.cshtml just in case. Now I'm getting: Sales:263 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Comment: Definitely a problem with the order of library inclusion and usage. See my updated answer. In short, make sure jQuery is loaded before using it. I copied and pasted your code and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I do see it now and have made changes accordingly. It is firing in the console as I type now, however now I'm getting; jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:55583/Employees/EmployeesAutocomplete?term=k 404 (Not Found).  It is not entering the JsonResult EmployeesAutocomplete. :( I appreciate all of your help with this.

Comment: That looks like a routing problem. Do you have any custom route definition  blocking the default routing  ? Don't worry about auto complete. Just try to get  that url you posted in prev comment directly on a browser to work

Comment: Quick change of the routing and it's all good. You helped me 2 days in a row!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For MVC architecture you must delete already embedded

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Jquery")
```

and

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Jqueryval")
```

from all `.cshtml` files at the end and for also `views/Shared/_layout.cshtml` at the end and put our jQuery suitable files on it's suitable `.cshtmls` files in head.

Put on head these files:

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```